# Getting a random number in a function in OCAML OR Telling compiler to evaluate function each time

Tags: random, functional-programming, ocaml, random-seed

I'm new to OCAML and was playing around with putting a marker on a random 5X5 square.  I've written the example program below.  "silly_method1" works but notice that it takes an argument.  I don't really have argument to pass in for what I want.  I'm just asking for a random number to create my robot on a particular square:

```
let create = {x = ( Random.int 4); y=3; face = North}
```

However, I get the same location each time.  This makes sense to me... sort of.  I'm assuming that the way I've set it up, "create" is basically a constant.  It's evaluated once and that's it! I've fixed it below in silly_method2 but look how ugly it is!

```
let silly_method2 _ = (Random.int 10)
```

Every time I have to call it, I have to pass in an argument even though I'm not really using it.

What is the correct way to do this?  There must be some way to have a function that takes no arguments and passes back a random number (or random tuple, etc.)
And possibly related... Is there a way to tell OCaml not to evaluate the function once and save the result but rather recalculate the answer each time?

Thank you for your patience with me!

Dave

```
let _ = Random.self_init()

let silly_method1 x = x + (Random.int 10)
let silly_method2 _ = (Random.int 10)
let report1 x = (print_newline(); print_string("report1 begin:  "); print_int (silly_method1 x); print_string("report1 end"); print_newline(); )
let report2 y = (print_newline(); print_string("report2 begin:  "); print_int(silly_method2 y ); print_string("report2 end"); print_newline(); )

let _ = report1 3
let _ = report1 3
let _ = report1 3

let _ = report2 3
let _ = report2 3
let _ = report2 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idiomatic way to define a function in OCaml that doesn't take an argument is to have the argument be `()`, which is a value (the only value) of type `unit`:

```
# let f () = Random.int 10;;
val f : unit -> int = <fun>
# f ();;
- : int = 5
# f ();;
- : int = 2
```

OCaml doesn't save function results for later re-use. If you want this behavior you have to ask for it explicitly using `lazy`.

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey.  For future readers (or my future self) remember that you signature will be "val f : unit -> int"  Also make sure when you use this method, call f() not just f.

Comment: In FP languages like OCaml, a function is a fairly ordinary first class value. If you just give the name of the function you're talking about that value--the function itself. So it doesn't represent a function call. After a short time this becomes natural and you don't even think about it.